# Separating and reversing a substring

Tags: c, string, reverse

I'm trying to add a property into my C code. Details are written below. Is there anybody who can help?? Btw it's forbidden to use any library other than stdio.h.

Reverse a given word in a sentence. When reversing the word, you must obey the following rules:

1. First 2 letters of the word will remain the same.
2. Add ‘-’ (dash) after the first 2 letters of the word.
3. Reverse the rest of the word.

For example:

Sentence: “This is the input sentence” Given Word: “This”
Output: “Th-si is the input sentence”

Sentence: “This is the input sentence” Given Word: “input”
Output: “This is the in-tup sentence”

Sentence: “This is the input sentence” Given Word: “sentence”
Output: “This is the input se-ecnetn”

Assume that given word will always be at least 4 letters and exist in the sentence.

I wrote a reversing function but i couldn't add the other details.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void put_word(char *word, char *sentence, int index)
{
    // Replace the chars of the sentence with the chars of
    // the word through the index

    // Two counter, one for sentence, other for word
    for (int i = index, c = 0; word[c] != '\0'; i++, c++)
    {
        sentence[i] = word[c];
    }
    return;
}

void reverse_word(char *word)
{
    int size = 0;
    for (int i = 0; word[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        size++;
    } // Size of the word
    char tmp;
    for (int i = 0; i < size / 2; i++) // string mirroring
    {
        tmp = word[i];
        word[i] = word[size -(i + 1)]; // +1 is for ignore \0
        word[size - (i + 1)] = tmp;
    }

    return;
}

int find_word(char *word, char *sentence)
{
    // Return index of the start of the word in sentence
    int counter = 0;
    for (int i = 0; sentence[i] != '\0'; i++)  // Stop at the end of the sentence
    {
        // If both sentence[i] and word[counter] == '\0' so this is
        // should return because of this have the word[counter] != '\0'

        if (sentence[i] == word[counter] && word[counter] != '\0')
        {
            counter++; // Iterate over word
        }
        else if (counter != 0) // Two options, or word is founded or not
        {
            if (word[counter] == '\0') // Indicates of the found point
            {
                return i - counter; // Basic math
            }
            counter = 0; // If not founded reset counter word
        }
    }
    return -1; // Not found
}

int main()
{
    char s[] = "This is the input sentence";
    char change_what[] = "input";
    int index = find_word(change_what, s);
    if (index == -1)
    {
        printf("Word %s not found!\n", change_what);
        return 1;
    }

    // As these functions work with pointers, the return is not necessary.
    reverse_word(change_what);
    put_word(change_what, s, index);
    

    printf("\"%s\"", s);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand.  You are talking about your C code, but tagged as C++.  The C and C++ are different languages.  For example, C++ has `namespace` and allows for overloading functions and operators.  Which language are you programming in (please remove the other tag).

Comment: @ThomasMatthews I actually tagged both languages ​​because I was asking about the solution of the algorithm. If you have a solution for c++, I can easily convert it to c :)

Comment: It's not clear what the question is, but at least one important insight is that the new string is going to be longer than the old string. So you're going to need to be doing some memory allocation, and copying, in addition to locating and replacing the chosen word. And I doubt if anyone gave you a C++ solution, you could convert that to C. C++ has a std::string class which probably makes this easier, which C completely lacks.

Comment: This looks like a homework assignment. An assignment is not a question, where are you stuck? Allocate memory one char more as input, copy first two bytes of input, then add a dash then copy the rest of the characters back to front. Use pointers, this is C. Additional points if you create separate / generic functions for each step.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I can reverse the given word but I have to keep the first two letters the same and put a '-' symbol and reverse the rest of the word. But the problem is I can't write the first two letters the same as the given word.

Comment: Why not break it down into separate tasks, and tackle each one separately. Your first task is to find the given word in the sentence. Write a function that can do that.

Comment: OK, take a step back. First, create functions for the string length determination and the reversal, *given a pointer & size*. Then do not change these functions, but create **separate code** to go through the steps I've indicated. You first have to analyze the problem and split it into separate parts, i.e. functions.

Comment: I've added the whole code. Maybe it can help to explain easily.

Comment: You're going to need to allocate more space to store the result, if you are adding a character (the '-'). Your input string 's' is a fixed size and can not be trivially expanded.

Comment: A string like char foo[] = "hi" declares 'foo' as an array of three characters, 'h', 'i' and the terminating '\0'. You will need to allocate a new array using malloc() to store your result, because it is longer than the input string. Then find the index of the word in your input string. Copy all of the input into the new array up to that point. Then insert the reversed and expanded word. Then copy the rest of the input. I'm not going to post an answer, because it's your homework, and you need to at least figure out how to do all that.

Comment: Actually, it's not clear from the question if you need to create a string like you describe, or just output on the terminal the desired output? If you just need to print it (and not store it in a string), it is much, much simpler.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes I've added the whole code. Maybe it can help to explain easily.